# Probability Question Likely Outcome of Event

Tags: probability

The probability that you will win a certain game is 0.8. If you play the game 12 times, what is the probability that you will win at least 7 times?

Comment: Do you know the Binomial Distribution?

Comment: I know what Binomial Distribution means, but that information wasn't provided for this question.

Comment: No, so it's a matter of recognizing (or assuming) that it must apply in this case, which is reasonable if the probability remains constant for each game

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $X$ is the number of wins in $n$ games then $X\sim\text{Binomial}(n,0.8)$